# Changing projection of QLR file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qlr

I have converted a ESRI *.lyr* file to a *.qlr* file in QGIS using the SLYR plugin. However, it does not give me the option to redefine the projection. If I change it in the traditional format by exporting the new file type and changing the CRS there changes the layer into a single polygon shape file and loses all the symbology etc.

Alternatively, if I change the CRS of the layer by right clicking it to my desired projection then the layer shifts away from my project area.

Has anyone got any suggestions? It is worth noting that, I cannot change the original ESRI *.lyr* projection either.